# How can I display the two images inside of this function?

Tags: python, imshow

I provide the following function to flip the image and its corresponding mask. Now I want to display two images and save them. How can I do that? I need to know this method more than others because it is related to my research work.

```
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torchvision.utils import save_image
import cv2 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import numpy as np
import cv2

## define functions
def t_random(min=0, max=1):
    return min + (max - min) * np.random.rand()


def t_randint(min, max):
    return np.random.randint(low=min, high=max)

class augCompose(object):

    def __init__(self, transforms=None):
        self.transforms = transforms

    def __call__(self, img, mask):

        if self.transforms is not None:
            for op, prob in self.transforms:
                if t_random() <= prob:
                    img, mask = op(img, mask)

        return img, mask

def RandomFlip(img, mask, FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT=True, FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM=True):

    if FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT and t_random() < 0.5:
        img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
        mask = cv2.flip(mask, 1)

    if FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM and t_random() < 0.5:
        img = cv2.flip(img, 0)
        mask = cv2.flip(mask, 0)
    return img, mask

# This function will read the image using its path with opencv
def Load_Image(Path):
    img = cv.imread(Path)[:,:,::-1] # opencv read the images in BGR format 
                                    # so we use [:,:,::-1] to convert from BGR to RGB
    return img

## Load the image
img = Load_Image("..........\\6192.jpg")
msk = Load_Image("...........\\6192.bmp")

## Call the function 
RandomFlip = RandomFlip(img, msk)

## how can I display these two flipped images?
```

Comment: A few minutes with Google will surely bring you to the relevant Stack Overflow posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the images using either OpenCV or Matplotlib.

If you wish to use OpenCV:

```py
## Load the image
img = Load_Image("..........\\6192.jpg")
msk = Load_Image("...........\\6192.bmp")

## Call the function 
flp_img, flp_msk = RandomFlip(img, msk)

## Display the image
cv2.imshow('image',flp_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

## Display the mask
cv2.imshow('mask',flp_msk)
cv2.waitKey(0)

## Saving the images
cv2.imwrite("flp_img", flp_img)
cv2.imwrite("flp_msk", flp_msk)
```

If you wish to use Matplotlib you can use the `plt.imshow` function, but we first need to recolor the image from BGR (the format used by OpenCV) to RGB (the format used by Matplotlib). We will use the same code for saving the images:

```py
## Load the image
img = Load_Image("..........\\6192.jpg")
msk = Load_Image("...........\\6192.bmp")

## Call the function 
flp_img, flp_msk = RandomFlip(img, msk)

## Display the image
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(flp_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()

## Display the mask
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(flp_msk, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()

## Saving the images
cv2.imwrite("flp_img", flp_img)
cv2.imwrite("flp_msk", flp_msk)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can plot them with just `plt` as follows:

```py
# make axes: images are arranged over one row
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

# you can change the size of the plot is required
fig_size = (12, 10)  # example base size

fig.set_figwidth(fig_size[0] * 2)  # where 2 is #columns
fig.set_figheight(fig_size[1] * 1)  # 1 is #rows

# plot the images on each axis
ax1.imshow(img)

# additionally you can specify a colormap, e.g.
ax2.imshow(msk, cmap='binary')

# you can set the title, axis labels, legends, as usual, e.g.
ax1.set_title('Image')
ax2.set_title('Mask')

# removes borders
fig.tight_layout()

# finally show the images
plt.show()
```

If you have more than two images you can rearrange them easily, in a grid-like fashion, by setting `nrows` and `ncols`.